# How can I write a procedure that gets levels i through j or a tree like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, database-design

I have a table like

```
        Users
-------------------------
id | ancestor_id | ....
-------------------------
 1 |    NULL     | ....
 2 |     1       | ....
 3 |     1       | ....
 4 |     3       | ....
 5 |     3       | ....
```

that would represent a tree like

```
   level 1           1
                   /  \ 
   level 2        2    3 
                      / \
   level 3           4   5
```

and I want to create a procedure that returns the `i`th through `j`th generation of descendants of a given user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DescendantsLevel 
   @user_id INT,
   @i INT,
   @j INT
AS
   ....
```

If `@j` is `NULL`, however, it returns all descendants beginning from generation `@i`.

**Examples:**

```
EXEC DescendantLevel @user_id=1,@i=2,@j=NULL
```

would return

```
-------------------------
id | ancestor_id | ....
-------------------------
 1 |    NULL     | ....
 2 |     1       | ....
 3 |     1       | ....
 4 |     3       | ....
 5 |     3       | ....
```

and

```
EXEC DescendantLevel @user_id=1,@i=1,@j=2
```

would return

```
        Users
-------------------------
id | ancestor_id | ....
-------------------------
 1 |    NULL     | ....
 2 |     1       | ....
 3 |     1       | ....
```

Several questions, I have:

- Is there a better value than `NULL` to represent some concept of "infinity" in SQL?
- How can I implement the procedure I've described?
- Is there a better way of designing the database in order to simplify the procedure?

Comment: Lookup recursive ctes. It will be the easiest way to solve this if you use this design. You might also look at the nested sets model as a better alternative to the adjacency list.

Comment: If `@i` is 2 in your first example then why is id #1 being returned?

Comment: Why not add a level column? Makes the query really simple.

Comment: Adding a level column adds a manually calculated column to the table - which adds complexity and can then get out of sync and cause other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (id INT NOT NULL, ancestor_id INT NULL)

DECLARE
    @id INT = 1,
    @i INT = 1,
    @j INT = 2

INSERT INTO @test (id, ancestor_id)
VALUES
    (1, NULL),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 3)

;WITH CTE_Tree AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        ancestor_id,
        1 AS lvl,
        id AS base
    FROM
        @test
    WHERE
        id = @id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.id,
        C.ancestor_id,
        P.lvl + 1 AS lvl,
        P.base AS base
    FROM
        CTE_Tree P
    INNER JOIN @test C ON C.ancestor_id = P.id
    WHERE
        lvl <= COALESCE(@j, 9999)
)
SELECT
    id,
    ancestor_id
FROM
    CTE_Tree
WHERE
    lvl BETWEEN @i AND COALESCE(@j, 9999)
```

This relies on no more than 9999 levels of recursion (actually the default limit on recursion for SQL Server is 100, so more than 100 levels and you'll get an error).